# How to turn string decimals into float?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
my_list=[['A','B','C','0.0'],['D','E','F','1.2'],['G','H','I','0'],['J','K','L','M']]
```

I tried these but they can only convert whole numbers into floats and leaves the rest as strings.

```
[[float(x) if x.isnumeric() else x for x in i] for i in my_list]
```

```
for i, sublist in enumerate(my_list):
     for j, x in enumerate(sublist):
            if x.isnumeric():
                my_list[i][j] = float(x)
```

**Expected output**

```
[['A','B','C',0.0],['D','E','F',1.2],['G','H','I',0],['J','K','L','M']]
```

Comment: As a rule, you never want to use text tests for stuff like this. If the goal is "something parsable as an X", then the solution is "parse it as an X and catch the exception if it fails". The parsers for `float` and `int` handle *many* more cases than simple string methods can verify. As you've discovered, a period is not considered a numeric character, nor is a minus sign (for negative numbers), the letter `e` (e.g. for the valid float `1.2e10`), etc. The `float`/`int` constructors have no trouble with leading or trailing whitespace too, but your string tests won't see them as numeric either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.isnumeric`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float) does not return `True` for float numbers represented as strings. It returns true for strings that only consists of numbers, `.` is not a number.

This is why your solution only converts integers, not floats.

The [best choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float) to check if a string is a float, and hence convert it - is to just try `float()` and catching the raised `ValueError` and simply continuing.

If you know the nesting is only one level deep, [deceze's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63487402/10305477) should do it great.

If there may be more nesting, you could try a recursive function-

```py
def convert_float(l: list):
    for i, v in enumerate(l):
        if type(v) == list:
            convert_float(v)
            continue
        try:
            l[i] = float(v)
        except ValueError:
            continue
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have no other criterion than "anything might or mightn't be a valid float", then just `try` them all:

```
def try_float(value):
    try:
        return float(value)
    except ValueError:
        return value

result = [[try_float(v) for v in l] for l in my_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `regex` to find this. Something like below:

```
In [105]: import re

In [106]: r = re.compile(r"^\d*[.,]?\d*$")

In [107]: [[float(v) if r.match(v) else v for v in l] for l in my_list]
Out[107]: 
[['A', 'B', 'C', 0.0],
 ['D', 'E', 'F', 1.2],
 ['G', 'H', 'I', 0.0],
 ['J', 'K', 'L', 'M']]
```